# neural network converges too fast and predicts blank results

Tags: neural-network, keras, image-segmentation

I am using a UNet model to train a segmentation algorithm with roughly 1,000 grayscale medical images and 1,000 corresponding masks where the section of interest in the medical image is white pixel and the background is black.

I am using dice loss and a similar dice score as an accuracy metric to account for the fact that my white pixels are generally less in number than the black background pixels. But I am still having a few problems when training

1) **The loss converges too fast.** If I have my SGD optimizer's learning rate at 0.01 for example, at around 2 epochs the loss (training and validation) will drop to 0.00009 and the accuracy shoots up and settles at 100% in proportion. Testing on an unseen set gives blank images.

**Assumption - Overfitting:**
I assumed this was due to overfitting, so I augmented the dataset as much as possible with rigid transformations - flipping and rotating, but still no help.
Also if I test the model against the same data I used to train it, it still predicts blank images. So does this mean it isn't a case of overfitting?

2)**Model doesn't look like it's even training.** I was able to check the model before it reduced all the test data to blackness, but even then the results would look like blurry versions of the original without segmenting the features highlighted by my training mask

3) **The loss vs epochs and accuracy vs epochs output charts are very smooth:** They present none of the oscillating behaviour that I expect to see when doing semantic segmentation. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47649786/what-fast-loss-convergence-indicates-on-a-cnn) related post a smooth chart usually occurs when there is only one class. I however assumed that my model would see the training masks (white pixels vs black pixels) and see that as a two class problem. Am I wrong in this assumption?

4) According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50181116/unet-segmentation-model-predicts-blank-image) post Dice is good for an unbalanced training set. I have also tried to get precision/recall/F1 results as they suggest, but was unable to do it and assuming it might be related to my 3rd issue where the model sees my segmentation task as a single class problem.

**TLDR:** How can I fix the black output results I am getting? Can you please help me clarify if my learning model is actually seeing my white and black pixels in each mask as two separate classes and if not what is it actually doing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [U-net low contrast test images, predict output is grey box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52946110/u-net-low-contrast-test-images-predict-output-is-grey-box)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your model is only predicting one class (the background/back pixels) because of the class imbalance.

> The loss converges too fast. If I have my SGD optimizer's learning rate at 0.01 for example, at around 2 epochs the loss (training and validation) will drop to 0.00009 and the accuracy shoots up and settles at 100% in proportion. Testing on an unseen set gives blank images.

Lower your learning rate. `0.01` is really high, so try something like `3e-5` for your learning and see how your model performs.
Also, having a 100% accuracy (supposedly you're using dice?) suggests that you're still using accuracy, so I believe that your model does not recognize that you're using dice/dice loss for training and evaluation(code snippets would be appreciated).

***Example:***

```py
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=TRAIN_SEG_LEARNING_RATE),              
              loss=dice_coef_loss, 
              metrics=[dice_coef])
```

> Also if I test the model against the same data I used to train it, it still predicts blank images. So does this mean it isn't a case of overfitting?

Try using `model.evaluate(test_data, test_label)`. If the evaluated performance is good (dice should be extremely low if you're only predicting 0s), then either your labels are messed in some way or there is something wrong with your pipeline.

**Possible Solutions if all else fails:**

- make sure to go through all the sanity checks in this [article](https://blog.slavv.com/37-reasons-why-your-neural-network-is-not-working-4020854bd607)
- You might not have enough data, so try to use a patchwise approach with random crops.
- Add more regularization (dropout, BatchNormalization, InstanceNormalization, increasing input image size, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not familiar with patchwise cropping, but I am currently running the model again after cropping each image so that white/black pixels are roughly the same. However, lets say there are slightly more white pixels now, what is stopping the model from being imbalanced and reducing my output to white images rather than black images as before? You also mentioned that my model is only predicting one class due to the imbalance. My understanding is that it is a two class problem (segmenting class 1 from class 0). Is that understanding incorrect?

Comment: There would need to be a __severe__ class imbalance for the model to learn produce white only images (same thing for models producing black only images). It was my assumption was that you had a severe class imbalance (significantly more background pixels than foreground pixels) because you're using medical images. 
Also, your understanding of your problem being a two class is correct. What I meant is that your model is only learning to predict 0s and settling for that because of the way your settings are configured (i.e. learning rate, model complexity, severe class imbalance, etc).