# unet produces gray predicted image

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am using the unet network that can be found [here](https://github.com/zhixuhao/unet)

I am having a strange issue that whenever I change the images in the test folder, the predicted images become gray boxes. I am currently just blurring the image. I have also blurred the images in the image folder and in the aug folder, and as long as I dont change the images in the test folder it works fine still. Am I missing a step to do this correctly? The code also produces gray images if I delete the predicted images.

I have also looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52946110/u-net-low-contrast-test-images-predict-output-is-grey-box), but the solutions either seem not to apply to my case, such as the learning rate, or I have done and they dont resolve the issue such as changing the line from `img=img/255` to `img/=255.`

In order to the blur the photos I wrote a python script that uses this to blur them:

`blurImg = cv2.blur(img,(10,10))`

The images are now saved to under a different name. So the original image is untouched. These images are still produce the expected results but the blurred image produces a gray image. Here is a link to the [images](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13eFfxmdpmbFho4mnNCXrvJ8AnyaEIWru/view?usp=sharing)

The code to blur the images:

```
import cv2  
import os

directory="./test"
counter=100
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".png"):
        pic=os.path.join(directory, filename)
        pic2=os.path.join(directory,str(counter)+filename[1:])
        print (pic2)
        img = cv2.imread(pic)
        blurImg = cv2.blur(img,(10,10))
        print(os.path.join(directory, filename))
        cv2.imwrite(pic2, blurImg)
        counter+=1
    else:
        continue
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: please provide code from all the part regarding transformation-saving-reloading not just that single line to be able help you.

Comment: @Geeocode I just added it. Thank you for looking into it

Comment: Welcome, what output you get with `print(pic2)`? Why `filename[1:]`?

Comment: @Geeocode i get the file path and the and then a the new name of the picture. I was just trying to create a new name for an image that was easy to trace back to the original one.

Comment: I know what, you intend to do, but I wanted to check your indexing is correct as python indexing goes from `0` and you indexed from `1` `filename[1:]`, which seems to be no sense.

Comment: @Geeocode yeah I wanted to just catch the number at first, since the names are 0.png. so I wanted to rename it 01.png. After I ran it I realized it wouldnt work on values that are two digits, but was too lazy to fix it.

Comment: Ok but his is crucial, please fix it, run it and come back wirh result.

Comment: @geeocode I renamed them by hand and it still produced the same result. It also produced this result when I would overwrite the original images with the new ones